# String input using % in Python based on number of items in array

Tags: python, mysql, string, data-science, python-itertools

I am writing functionality in python that uses itertools.combinations to generate an array of combinations based on another array of items. This new array is used to feed a SQL query based on the number of items in an array. The grouping of combinations (r value in itertools.combinations) is a dynamic value.

```
 array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
 arrayDerived = list(combinations(array,2))
```

arrayDerived = [[1,2],[1,3] .....[9,0]]

Depending on the number of items in the combination, I will adjust the SQL query.

```
query = 'select * from %s where '
n= NoInCombination
x=1
while x < n:
    query = query + " %s =\'x\' AND"
    x =x+1
while x==n:
    query = query + " %s =\'x\'"
    x=x+1
```

once my query is built, How do I properly specify the strings (the D portion of the Code below) based on a dynamic amount of %s

ex:

```
 for d in arrayDerived:
     cur.execute(query%(TABLE_NAME,D))
```

Comment: which db are you using? you should use sqlalchemy to implement this

Comment: i am pretty sure that your query won't work at all. fist you can use $s for table names or for cplumn names .you could check https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/

Comment: @nbk since query is a string, it follows the normal string conventions.  I have used %s to input dynamic names into queries many times. My question is moreso geared towards passing the strings in a list/array when using the % convention.